beforeinstallprompt event not firing when using firebase in react app
I've a React app with a button to prompt users to install the PWA using the beforeinstallprompt event.
But when I add firebase to my project, the event stops firing. Removing firebase makes it work as expected.
My App.js file:
import { useEffect } from 'react'

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore'

const app = initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyBXWlTpsD1IwNVk4eR7xLLwawRKbXQv8ZI',
    authDomain: 'proj3-8bf4f.firebaseapp.com',
    projectId: 'proj3-8bf4f',
    storageBucket: 'proj3-8bf4f.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '649235921586',
    appId: '1:649235921586:web:36597201f19d0ffe02e7ab'
})

const data = await getDocs(collection(getFirestore(app), 'data'))
console.log(data)

function App() {
    let install = null

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
            install = e
            console.log(install)
        })
    }, [])

    async function handleInstall() {
        console.log(install)

        if (install) {
            await install.prompt()
            const { outcome } = await install.userChoice
            if (outcome === 'accepted') {
                install = null
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleInstall}>Install</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App


I'm a beginner and I've no clue of why/what is happening. Can you please take a look?
